# Using telescope with lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I tried the commands as per https://github.com/laravel/telescope:

```
composer require laravel/telescope --dev

php artisan telescope:install
```

The command resulted in the error below:

```
There are no commands defined in the "telescope" namespace.
```

Tried updating the dependencies by composer update but still the issue persists.

```
composer update

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 0 installs, 29 updates, 0 removals
  - Updating illuminate/contracts (v5.7.9 => v5.7.10): Loading from cache
  - Updating illuminate/support (v5.7.9 => v5.7.10): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/filesystem (v5.7.9 => v5.7.10): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/session (v5.7.9 => v5.7.10): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/pipeline (v5.7.9 => v5.7.10): Loading from cache
  - Updating illuminate/http (v5.7.9 => v5.7.10): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/container (v5.7.9 => v5.7.10): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/routing (v5.7.9 => v5.7.10): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/events (v5.7.9 => v5.7.10): Loading from cache
  - Updating illuminate/view (v5.7.9 => v5.7.10): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/translation (v5.7.9 => v5.7.10): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/validation (v5.7.9 => v5.7.10): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/database (v5.7.9 => v5.7.10): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/console (v5.7.9 => v5.7.10): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/queue (v5.7.9 => v5.7.10): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating illuminate/pagination (v5.7.9 => v5.7.10): Loading from cache
  - Updating illuminate/log (v5.7.9 => v5.7.10): Loading from cache
  - Updating illuminate/hashing (v5.7.9 => v5.7.10): Loading from cache
  - Updating illuminate/config (v5.7.9 => v5.7.10): Loading from cache
  - Updating illuminate/cache (v5.7.9 => v5.7.10): Loading from cache
  - Updating illuminate/bus (v5.7.9 => v5.7.10): Loading from cache
  - Updating illuminate/broadcasting (v5.7.9 => v5.7.10): Loading from cache
  - Updating illuminate/auth (v5.7.9 => v5.7.10): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating laravel/lumen-framework (v5.7.1 => v5.7.2): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating phpunit/php-code-coverage (6.0.8 => 6.1.3): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating phpunit/phpunit (7.4.0 => 7.4.3): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating aws/aws-sdk-php (3.69.4 => 3.69.13): Downloading (100%)
  - Updating league/flysystem (1.0.47 => 1.0.48): Downloading (100%)
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files



php artisan telescope:install


There are no commands defined in the "telescope" namespace.
```

Does it mean we need to wait till laravel/lumen-framework v5.7.7+ to use telescope with lumen?

Comment: Lumen is not Laravel (and doesn't have views by default), so I guess, yes, you'd need to wait until (if at all) it's available for Lumen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comment by Mohamed Said(a laravel developer):

Telescope isn't adapted for lumen yet.

Please refer the github issue: https://github.com/laravel/telescope/issues/112

Answer (score 0):

First: the teleport namespace is not needed. You can always register the service providers in bootstrap/app.php.
But this is not the problem. I registered the providers and got this error message

> Call to undefined method
>   Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router::middlewareGroup().

Lumen's router class is not compatible with the Laravel's. The only solution would be to get the code, create a fork and "translate" the Laravel functions into Lumen's.